# how to insert list into list using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have lists like..

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[7,3,4]
```

i need output like

```
l3=[[1,2,3],[7,3,4]]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it in pandas, you can do it in just normal python.

Comment: sorry i dont need to do pandas.....sorry...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do something like this:

```
>>> l1=[1,2,3]
>>> l2=[7,3,4]
>>> [l1, l2]
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this

```
l3 = [l1,l2]
```

Comment: and i have another one doubt

Comment: is it possible to converts particular columns to convert lists..?

Comment: in my dataframe there are 5 columns...i wants convert particular 3 columns into lists

Answer (score 2):

For:
`l1 = [1, 2, 3]` and 
`l2 = [7, 3, 4]` and
`l3 = []`
you can:

#### append elements

`l3.append(l1)` and 
`l3.append(l2)`

#### create directly

`l3 = [l1, l2]`

#### add

`l3 = [l1] + [l2]`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update not requiring pandas, you can simply do this:

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[7,3,4]

l3 = [l1] + [l2]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: That is exactly the output that I'm getting. Are you sure you included the square brackets?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use

```
l3=[l1,l2]
```

If you want to insert l2 into l1 at some particular index you can make use of .insert function of lists

```
list.insert(index,object)
l1.insert(2,l2)
```

Hope it helps.